# Keeping dialog box on top

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Can anyone please guide me. I am having difficulty keeping dialog box on top of webview (within MainActivity).

Basically, I have given a prompt to switch on WiFi if there's no internet connection.
The problem is when this dialog appears, if the user accidentally touches the background (occupied by webview which covers entire screen), the dialog disappears.

How do I keep it on top always, until and unless the user clicks one of the buttons (settings or cancel) within the dialog.

I am also using another dialogbox with a progressbar while the page loads. It also has the same problem (disapperars on touching the surrounding area on screen). What is happening is actually, the webview is coming on top of dialog.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behaviour for dialogs since (I believe) ICS.

Specify `myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` to disable it.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)